# PostgreSQL - get previous row and average

Tags: postgresql

I'm using this SQL query to minus current row from the previous row

output = current row - previous row

```
SELECT x.price_index FROM
(SELECT date_time, price - LAG(price) OVER (ORDER BY date_time
ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) AS price_index FROM my_table) as x
```

But the problem is first not sure how to get the previous 5 rows. 2nd is the current average previous 5 rows minus the previous average of 6~10 rows

problem 1 (solved)

```
output = current row - previous row (row number 5)
```

SQL query

```
SELECT x.price_index FROM
    (SELECT date_time, price - LAG(price, 5) OVER (ORDER BY date_time
    ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) AS price_index FROM my_table) as x
```

problem 2:
output = current average total of 5 previous rows (row number 1(current)~ 5) - previous average total of 6~10 previous rows (row number 6~10)

Comment: [`lag`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/14/functions-window.html) takes an offset, so if you want the previous 5 rows you can use `lag(price, 1)`, `lag(price, 2)`, ..., `lag(price, 5)`.

Comment: ok, how about average?

Comment: See documentation for [Window Function Calls](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-expressions.html#SYNTAX-WINDOW-FUNCTIONS). The `avg()` function, like other aggregate functions has a corresponding window version. What you are looking for in particular in the *frame_clause*.

Comment: @Nurdin Add the 5 values, divide by 5. It would help if you provided us with a schema, sample rows, and your expected results.